# How to reference an unused parameter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parameters, devexpress

Back in the days of C/C++, Microsoft had a `#define`, which allowed programmers to reference an unused parameter. The declaration, part of windef.h, is:

```
#define UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(P) {(P)=(P);}
#define UNREFERENCED_LOCAL_VARIABLE(L) {(L)=(L);}
```

Whatever the exact name and syntax, the line had the effect of

1. Telling the compiler to not flag this unused parameter as a warning
2. The later stages of the compiler was smart enough to not include the line in the binary (or so I recall)
3. Visually tells the viewer that the unreferenced parameter was not an oversight.

Is there a similar syntax in C#?

Although it makes no difference for this question, but the DevExpress CodeRush Visual Studio add-in flags all unused parameters, even in event handlers, as a warning.

NOTE:
As I stated in my comment, I do not want to use `pragma` blocks. The purpose is to add a line of code that references the parameter for warning sake but adds none to trivial overhead, like what the windef.h header file macro did.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe [the discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) `_` is what you are looking for:

```
void Foo(string parameter)
{
   _ = parameter;
}
```

Comment: Normally the `_` means "there is a parameter being passed in but I am not going to use it, so for example the lamda expression `thing.Any(_ => 1);` seeing `_ = parameter` would look very strange.

Comment: it has some use to me, though it's more a language hack : `_ = parameter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));`, so you can "nullcheck" in a more more concise manner.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `SuppressMessage` attribute you can suppress warnings where ever you want:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "isChecked")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1804:RemoveUnusedLocals", MessageId = "fileIdentifier")]
static void FileNode(string name, bool isChecked)
{
   string fileIdentifier = name;
   string fileName = name;
   string version = String.Empty;
}
```

This also gives the reader an explicit understanding that this is intended behavior.

More on the [SuppressMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Isn't this similar to using a pragma, or is this portable?

Comment: May or may not be similar. This suggested answer does not resolve the question, nor does the suggested answer work. Visual Studio 2012 already does not complain about these warnings, only Code Rush, which ignores the SuppressMessage attribute.

Comment: Consider also adding the `Justification` argument, because otherwise you'll get another warning about lack of thereof.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax to disable and re-enable specific warnings. Surround the code that declares the unused/unreferenced paramter:

```
#pragma warning disable <warning-number>

// ... code that declares the unused parameter

#pragma warning restore <warning-number>
```

Where the `<warning-number>` above would be the warning number issued by the compiler that you wish to suppress. Presumably that would be [C# warning number 219](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kycwe2x%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I do not want to disable the warning or use disable/enable pragma statements. I was after something similar to what Microsoft defined in the Windowx.h header file of the SDK.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure I understand your reasoning for that.

Comment: This doesn't indicate *which* parameter is unused.

Answer (score 2):

Using pragma statements only allow turning on or turning off compiler warnings. Since it is most likely you only want to affect the file you are working in, this will cause problems if someone later decides to disable the warning project wide. Every file compiled after the file with the pragma restore in it may report an unwanted warning.
Embedded developers will recognize this as the common problem of trying to enable and disable interrupts without knowing what the previous interrupt status was.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a hack that you might use:

```
   namespace YourComapany.Tools{
       class CS
       {
           public static void UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER<T>(T t) {if(t == null) {T d=t;}
       }
   };
...
CS.UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(whatever);
```

Comment: I would vote the answer down, because the answer gives a warning: `Unnecessary assignment of a value to 'd'`, which thereby makes the answer not an answer. Maybe this answer worked with VS2017 and broke with VS2019. Sorry, I just saw the answer now and this answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: Would this work? (I have warning level set to 4, and don't get any notice).
`namespace YourComapany.Tools {
        class CS {
            public static void UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER<T>( T t ) {
                if(t == null) { foo(); }
            }
            static void foo() { }
        };
};`